# What's the difference between a is string and a !is string in c#

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I need to understand the meaning of `!is` in c#. I understand the `is` keyword. I expected that `a !is b` would be the same as `!(a is b)`.
However, after testing, I found out that this is not the case. I just need to know what it means and when it may be useful.

I have checked the documentation for is.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is

From the navigation, it appears the only type testing keyword is `is`. There's no obvious reference to !is. I can find none in the same page as is, yet the compiler doesn't fail when I use !is. (Is this a bug?).

**previousStageResult.Data is defined as object.**

```
// this
var previousResultIsInvalid = previousStageResult.Data !is Dictionary<string, int>;

// returns the same thing as
var previousResultIsInvalid = previousStageResult.Data is Dictionary<string, int>;
```

```
// What I expect:
var previousResultIsInvalid = previousStageResult.Data !is Dictionary<string, int>;

// should be the same as
var previousResultIsInvalid = !(previousStageResult.Data is Dictionary<string, int>);

// if it is even valid at all
```

Thank you.

Comment: `!is` doesn't mean anything. It's not a keyword.

Comment: Postfix-! on a non-nullable reference in c#8 and later is the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving). It's a postfix operator on the reference to the left of the `is`; it isn't a boolean negation of the `is`

Comment: yeah, this is "test whether blah.Data, which I definitely think isn't null, is a dictionary" - in terms of parens, it is `(previousStageResult.Data!) is Dictionary<string, int>`; which is pointless, because `is` doesn't care whether values are `null` or not :)

Comment: this is a fun question, but sadly it is based on a false premise...

Comment: @MarcGravell Even more sadly, it's already a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I had thought the `!` was an operator on the is. Now I understand better. Just to clarify I tested `a!is b` and I find it valid, although it's unreadable.